# Creating a Priority Queue via Multiset

Tags: c++, multiset

I'm working on an assignment for class where we have to create a priority queue object using multiset.  I pretty much know what to do, but I'm having a little trouble with the syntax of multiset.  Here's my class definition for my priority queue:

```
template< typename E >
class MyPriorityQueue
{
public:
    MyPriorityQueue();
    ~MyPriorityQueue();

    MyPriorityQueue(const MyPriorityQueue &);
    MyPriorityQueue operator=(const MyPriorityQueue &);

    void put(E item);
    E get();
    bool empty();
    int size();

private:
    multiset<E> queue;
};
```

When I compile the code, I get error messages at the "multiset queue" line about "missing type specifier" and "unexpected token preceding ';'".  I've probably formatted that line incorrectly, or was I incorrect in assuming that multiset can be used to store only one variable?

Any help is much appreciated.  :)  Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

`queue` is a type if you have a `using namespace std;` that's accessible from your priority queue class. So saying

```
 multiset<E> queue;
```

Is illegal.

Don't have `#using namespace` statements in header files for this reason among others. Rename your `queue` to something else, `myQ` for example, but definitely remove the `#using namespace std` from your .h, or one of the files it includes.